# Can we retrieve Serial No, Issuer DN, Subject Details of a x509 Certificate in IOS SDK iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, openssl

Can we retrieve X509 Certificate details(Serial No, Issuer DN, Subject Details) using ios sdk or Openssl?

Comment: That would be against Apple's Terms and Guidelines.

Comment: Hi Emil, i would just like to know details of a third party x509 certificate. whats harm in that.

Comment: Nothing, just mentioning it ;)

Comment: That would not be in violation of any of Apple's guidelines, @Emil. In fact, the Security framework includes APIs for reading a certificate's metadata.

Comment: In that case, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately on iOS the Security framework does not give you quite the same level of access to serial numbers, DN and altNames as one gets on OSX.

You are however able to get access to the DER certificate in its raw form (SecIdentityCopyCertificate()) and have a few cursory functions like SecCertificateCopySubjectSummary() to extract the most minimal stuff.

If you want to get at the serial. DN and (alt)subject - then you'll have to parse the DER on todays iOS. A fairly easy way is to use OpenSSL for that.

I found http://atastypixel.com/blog/easy-inclusion-of-openssl-into-iphone-app-projects/ easy to install/use.

Once you have that in place you can examine the DER:

```
CFDataRef der = SecCertificateCopyData(cert);
const unsigned char * ptr = CFDataGetBytePtr(der);
int len = CFDataGetLength(der);

d2i_X509(&x509,&ptr,len);    
_sha1 = [(__bridge NSData *)der sha1];
```

and then you are off to the races with things like:

```
X509_NAME * names_s = X509_get_subject_name(x509);
X509_NAME * names_i = X509_get_issuer_name(x509);
GENERAL_NAMES * subjects = X509_get_ext_d2i( x509, NID_subject_alt_name, 0, 0 );

ASN1_INTEGER *serial = X509_get_serialNumber(x509);
unsigned  long s = ASN1_INTEGER_get(serial);
```

with a somewhat painful translation of all that as needed:

```
+(NSArray *)names:(GENERAL_NAMES *)sANs {

int i, numAN = sk_GENERAL_NAME_num( sANs );
NSMutableArray * out = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:numAN];

for( i = 0; i < numAN; ++i ) {
    GENERAL_NAME *sAN = sk_GENERAL_NAME_value( sANs, i );

    if( sAN->type == GEN_DNS) {
        unsigned char *dns;
        int len = ASN1_STRING_to_UTF8( &dns, sAN->d.dNSName );
        if (len >0) {
            [out addObject:[[NSString alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithBytes:dns length:len] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
            OPENSSL_free( dns );
        }
    }
    .. more types as needed ..
}
return out;
}
```

Thanks,

Dw.

Comment: Do you know if there's a better way now to extract "Not valid after" date using Swift?

Answer (score 1):

You can find the details you wanted in [NSURLProtectionSpace](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLProtectionSpace_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSURLProtectionSpace) class.

Make sure you check for [distinguished names](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLProtectionSpace_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURLProtectionSpace/distinguishedNames) property in the class.