# C++ macOS - Programmatically retrieve code sign certificate information

Tags: c++, macos, code-signing

On Windows, there is a possibility to get a .exe/.dll code sign certificate using [CryptQueryObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380264(v=vs.85).aspx).

Is there any c++ (or objective-c) alternative to retrieve the **Subject name** and the **Serial number** of the certificate which has been used to code sign an .app on macOS ?

I don't have problem to code sign my .app using xcode, and when Im in the terminal, Im able to see that my code has been sign with the proper certificate.

---

**EDIT:**

The idea is to get something like this command line, but in C++.

```
codesign -v --extract-certificates MyApp.app/ 
| openssl x509 -inform DER -in codesign0 -text 
| grep "Serial" -A 1
```

Comment: Of course you could always call out to that shell command from C++, which is what I would do. But it would be interesting to see if there exists a c++ utility provided by the system.

Comment: Currently, I used [openSSL to read the serial number/subject name](http://fm4dd.com/openssl/certserial.htm) and my certificate is [read from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6689584/how-to-convert-the-certificate-string-into-x509-structure). The only thing I need to do now, is to extract the certificate string from my executable. I think I can make something working using std::system, but I will also prefer to use a pure C++ call for that. I dont know if a fopen on macOS executable could read/extract the certificate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer might not be optimal for now, and need a lot of refactoring, specially because Im not a macOS developper that why I mix too much c/c++/objective-c.

**Please feel free to edit this code**, specially if there is a memory leak, I dont know what I have the CFRelease in this.

So based on different sources, I made a solution that programmatically extract the subject common name (CN) and serial number of the certificate from a macOS bundle/app/executable. Here are the source I based my code on:

- [Apple codesign source code to extract-certificates](https://opensource.apple.com/source/security_systemkeychain/security_systemkeychain-39457/src/cs_dump.cpp.auto.html)
- [An example of how to read SecCertificateRef data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8485286/can-we-retrieve-serial-no-issuer-dn-subject-details-of-a-x509-certificate-in-i)
- [An example of how to read certificate from bytes using openSSL](http://fm4dd.com/openssl/certserial.htm)

Here the code:

```
#include <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#include <CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h>
#include <Security/Security.h>

#include <openssl/bio.h>
#include <openssl/x509.h>
#include <openssl/pem.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {    

    NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"/Path/To/Your/Codesign/MyApp.app"];
    CFURLRef path = (__bridge CFURLRef)url;

    SecStaticCodeRef codeRef;
    SecStaticCodeCreateWithPath(path, kSecCSDefaultFlags, &codeRef);      

    SecCSFlags flags = kSecCSInternalInformation
    | kSecCSSigningInformation
    | kSecCSRequirementInformation
    | kSecCSInternalInformation;

    CFDictionaryRef api;
    SecCodeCopySigningInformation(codeRef, flags, &api);

    CFArrayRef certChain = (CFArrayRef)CFDictionaryGetValue(api, kSecCodeInfoCertificates);

    // Get the first certificate from the .app 
    // use the CFIndex count = CFArrayGetCount(certChain); 
    // If you want to process all certificates in a loop (same to codesign source code).
    SecCertificateRef cert = SecCertificateRef(CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(certChain, 0));
    CFDataRef der = SecCertificateCopyData(cert);

    // Use solution from the example or using NSData*.
    //const unsigned char* data = CFDataGetBytePtr(der);    
    //int len = CFDataGetLength(der);
    NSData* data = (__bridge NSData*)der;    

    BIO* bio = BIO_new_mem_buf((void *)[data bytes], (int)[data length]);
    X509* certssl = NULL;
    X509_NAME* subName = NULL;
    X509_NAME_ENTRY* entry = NULL;
    unsigned char* subjectStr;    

    // Read certificate from the BIO 
    // Note that SecCertificateRef is in DER format
    if ( !( certssl = d2i_X509_bio(bio, NULL)))
        return -1;    

    // Get Subject common name (CN)
    if( !( subName= X509_get_subject_name(certssl)))
        return -1;   

    if( !( entry = X509_NAME_get_entry(subName, X509_NAME_get_index_by_NID(subName, NID_commonName, -1))))
        return -1;   

    ASN1_STRING_to_UTF8(&subjectStr, X509_NAME_ENTRY_get_data(entry));    

    // Extract the certificate's serial number.
    ASN1_INTEGER* asn1_serial = X509_get_serialNumber(certssl);
    if (asn1_serial == NULL)
        return -1;    

    // Convert serial number into a char buffer.
    BIGNUM* bnser = ASN1_INTEGER_to_BN(asn1_serial, NULL);
    char* serialStr = BN_bn2hex(bnser);    

    X509_free(certssl);
    BIO_free_all(bio);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are returning before freeing the memory for bio and certssl in negative cases, use unique ptr with custom deleter